# Algorithm to compute a common denominator of a finite set of rational numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ be fixed, but unknown, and assume that we know a number $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a number $N \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ such that $x_1 N,\dots,x_n N \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $q \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$, and assume that we have an algorithm which can compute any finite initial segment of the q-adic representation of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Then do we have an *efficient* algorithm to actually compute a number $N \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ with $x_1 N,\dots,x_n N \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: How «efficient» should it be? What is the complexity you have at your disposal right now?

Comment: At the moment I only have brute force. Anything better would be helpful.

Comment: Would it help if we knew a constant $C \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is $N \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ such that $x_1 N,\dots,x_n N \in \mathbb{Z}$ and all prime factors of $N$ are smaller than $C$?

Comment: The motivation for this question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863776/infinite-sum-involving-q-adic-representations-of-whole-numbers-and-q-factori).